# narrow a window function's

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have just started learning sql and I have a question:

What function to narrow a window function's application to a subgroup within a data set?
is it OVERLAY(PARTITION BY, OVER (partition by),SUBGROUP(PARTITION BY , or SESSION(PARTITION BY ?

Thanks

couple googling but still zonk

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If your values figuares are in column `column_sale`  and you want to have a subgroup by the entries of the column `column_state` then this is the window function:  `Select *, sum(column_sale) over (partition by column_state)`